# How to pass static data of an object via network?

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to code a simple program to pass an object using network. As the object may contain static data, I have no idea how to pass that data, because after the data is received, the static data would be reset. How's that possible?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class client {
    private static int PORT = 8901;
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        socket = new Socket("localhost", PORT);
        dataStruct ds = new dataStruct();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataStruct.khar = 1;
        oos.writeObject(ds);
        oos.close();
    }
}
class dataStruct implements Serializable{
    static int khar = 0;
    public void setData(int khar){
        this.khar = khar;
    }
}
```

This is my client, and the following is my server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8901);
        Game game = new Game();
        Game.Player player1 = game.new Player(listener.accept(), 1);
        player1.start();
    }
}

class Game {
    class Player extends Thread {
        int turn;
        Player opponent;
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream input;

        public Player(Socket socket, int turn) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.turn = turn;
            try {
                input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
            }
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                dataStruct ds = (dataStruct)input.readObject();
                System.out.println(ds.khar);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Player died: " + e);
            } finally {
                try {socket.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you seeing an error with the code you posted? If so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as static data contained in an object. An object, i. e. instance of a class, has only instance data. The static data belongs to the class, not to any specific instance. If you use the Java serialization mechanism without an own serialization strategy but by just using defaults, of course the static data is not transferred, as you are serializing an instance and the static data is not related to the instance directly, but only indirectly by being related to the class the object is an instance of.

Comment: Thanks! So in order to transfer the data I have to add some serialization mechanism of my own?

Comment: There are many ways. You can make own serialization (though serializing class state with an instance is most probably not the right thing to do), or you can transform your static data to instance data, or you can recreate the static data on the receiving side, depending on what it is, ... If e. g. the static field holds a counter of how many instances are around, the best way would be to just increase the counter by one on deserialization on receiver side. But what to do and how heavily depends on the actual concrete use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Sending static data is not possible since static data are ignored  during the serialization process.

Instead you can use a DTO (Data Transfer Object) which is basically a simple bean with only light Types as fields (String, Long, etc. No complexe types as LocalDateTime for exemple) representing  your real object.

First step server side : create a DTO from your object
 If you want to send a DataStruct Object, convert  it as a DataStructDTO object:

```
public class DataStructDTO{
    private int khar;
    public DataStructDTO (DataStruct dataStruct) {
    //since your  only data is static, dataStruct  parameter is not needed... But if you add any other instance properties, you will need it.
    this.khar = DataStruct.*getKhar*();
    }

    // implements getter and setter
```

Then send it by network.

And, parse it to get your  data:

```
DataStruct.setKhar(dataStructDTO.getKhar)
```

By the way, with java conventions, class names start with an UpperCase (you should have DataStruct instead of dataStruct for instance.
LowerFirstCase are for variables names)